# The equivalent of a live-CD for a smartphone

Tags: livecd

Is there any way of running an OS in a smartphone without installing it on the device? That would be the equivalent of a live-CD for a PC. I intend to test several BSD distributions on a phone, that could be an Android or Windows.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't about Unix or Linux. It's about booting an alternative OS on a smartphone.

Comment: @roaima: it is about booting Unix or Linux on a smartphone. My intention is to boot some version of BSD on it.

Comment: Please update your question to make that clear. As it stands there is no reference to either Unix or Linux anywhere in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a BIOS or EFI to set from which device the phone should start up. Then you could use the external SD card as Live CD, or maybe even the USB port.

But do we have something like BIOS for our phones? I haven't heard anything abou this. Of course it has it, but how can you activate it?

When your (Android) phone is rooted, there are these tools that can install a new kernel. These are closest to this, but I don't have a rooted phone at the moment, and can't tell you much more about this.

Answer (score 1):

On a rooted Android smartphone you can install a bootloader.

The bootloader intercepts the booting process so it can be modified to make it point to a different storage destination (SD card, for example) to load the OS.

In that way you can have more than one OS on the same phone.

Answer (score 0):

The nearest thing to what you're asking would be an ad-hoc
[PostMarketOS](https://postmarketos.org) build in which
you load a custom kernel from USB in `fastboot`
which then mounts the `rootfs` from the network.